# Lookup Between two Lists - Workflow or Lookup Columns?

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, audience-targeting

I have two lists (A and B) that are used to manage sensitive customer questions. Questions are entered into list A and the data is copied into list B via workflows.

List B is used by a small group of users to answer the question (through audience targeting)

The answer should then be displayed in a read only column in List A, answers are likely to be lengthy and being able to enter rich text (Bold,Bullet point and hyperlinks) is preferable.

I've tried to do this through lookup columns but I believe I can only use single line text values so i'm limited to 255 characters.

Is there a  way to do this through workflows where the answer field in List A will still be read only?

If I've over engineered this or there's an easier way of solving my problem please let me know!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. You have to keep answer filed read only from list A, for particular users

Comment: That's right - a small group of users should only be able to modify the answer field

Comment: Which Platform you are using to build workflow 2010/2013?

Comment: I can use either

Comment: You Can Use Permission Break Inheritance, It Will break the permission for Item level. Then set new permission on item level for users

Comment: I could but I thought breaking permissions affects all items in a list and not a targeted column like I would require